# Obter registros que possuem valores iguais

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero obter os registros da tabela contato que tenham o mesmo e-mail. Só que o e-mail é um campo da tabela email pois desta forma o contato pode ter vários e-mails (One To Many).

```
// Tabela contato

id name
1  Alladin
2  Dumbo
3  Pluto

// Tabela email
id email               contact_id
1  dumbo@disney.com    2
2  alladin@disney.com  1
3  dumbo@disney.com    3
```

Eu preciso obter os dois registros que possuem o mesmo e-mail e que sejam contatos diferentes, por exemplo:

```
id name  email
2  Dumbo dumbo@disney.com
3  Pluto dumbo@disney.com
```

Eu tentei a seguinte query mas sem sucesso:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, e.email FROM contato c
INNER JOIN email e ON e.contact_id = c.id
WHERE e.email IN (SELECT e2.email FROM email e2 GROUP BY e2.email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Uma saída assim (https://i.imgur.com/PoEFYFh.png) resolveria?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, resolveria sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso, basta você fazer o JOIN entre suas duas tabelas, agrupando-as pelo endereço de e-mail e filtrando o resultado para manter os grupos que possuem 2 ou mais usuários para aquele e-mail.

Você chegou perto disso na sua SQL:

```sql
SELECT e.email, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ', ') as names
FROM contato c
JOIN email e ON e.contact_id = c.id
GROUP BY e.email
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Assim, a saída será uma lista de e-mails que possuem contatos duplicados acompanhado de uma coluna com os nomes dos contatos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!